# Shortest path from cities to gas stations (No fuel, but roads are weighted)

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

In a directed graph with weights on the edges, representing the length of the different roads between
nodes. Some of the nodes are gas stations, the others are cities.
How can I find the closest gas station to each city? There is no issue with fuels. The weights are just
the lengths of the roads between nodes.

I thought of using Dijkstra from every single node that is not a gas station (N1,N2,...) and by having a key to each node of "True", "False",
having true if it is a gas station (G1,G2,...,), then return the closest node (Ni) with key "True", to some Gas Station (Nj).

Not sure about the complexity. It seems like O(Dijkstra * size of (N1,N2,...)),
and then for each Ni, go linearly over the array and return the smallest node with "True" key.
Not sure if this is a valid way, I'd like to get some help and perhaps something that is more efficient.

Comment: If the weights are non-negative, then Dijkstra should be the best option AFAIK. If they are possibly negative, then Bellman–Ford should be used instead.

Comment: All weights are positive.
How would I implement Dijkstra here? Run it from every Node N1,...,Nj like I said?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be solved using just one run of the Dijkstra algorithm, but with a twist. While usually when implementing Dijkstra you set zero distance only to one vertex you start with, to solve this problem you set it for all your gas stations' vertices. Thus, you also need to add these zero-distance vertices to the priority queue (heap) at the initialization. Apart from the initialization algorithm stays the same.